# DocuSign SOAP API CreateEnvelope draft question

Tags: docusignapi

We are attempting to do a SOAP API call to a DocuSign account using the SOAPUI program and we are wanting the envelope to be created as a draft. Currently we only have access to the "CreateAndSendEnvelope" method so we don't have access to use the "state" xml tag so that we can create the envelope as a "draft" by using the "CreateEnvelope" method. The SOAP API guide from DocuSign is not 100 percent clear when it comes to these two methods because it says they are very similar and it doesn't show the schema for the "CreateEnvelope" method.

Can anyone verify that I am not able to create an envelope as a draft using the "CreateAndSendEnvelope" method and that the only way I would be able to do so would be to use the "CreateEnvelope" method?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`CreateAndSendEnvelope` cannot be used for `Draft Envelopes`. `CreateEnvelope` is used to create a Draft status envelope. But since you are doing a new Integration, it is recommended to use [REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference). Sample response for `CreateEnvelope` call would look like below (check status will always be Created):

```
<CreateEnvelopeResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
         <CreateEnvelopeResult>
            <RecipientStatuses/>
            <TimeGenerated>2020-02-18T22:30:33.4707464</TimeGenerated>
            <EnvelopeID>033b9ca5-ac56-467a-99c5-63e2a37b9eef</EnvelopeID>
            <Subject/>
            <UserName>Amit Sender</UserName>
            <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
            <Status>Created</Status>
```

Comment: Thank you Amit for answering my question! It is great to have a concrete answer as whether I can do this or not. You are much appreciated!